# How can I get Outlook Rooms without going through entire address list

Tags: c#, powershell, outlook

I have the following in Powershell:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $ConfRooms = $Outlook.Session.GetGlobalAddressList().AddressEntries | ?{$_.Name -match "^Conf Room"} | %{$_.Name}
```

and the following in C#:

```
Outlook.AddressEntry addEntry in objOutlook.Session.GetGlobalAddressList().AddressEntries
```

The last one is followed with a:

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(addEntry.Name, "^Conf Room"))
```

The issue I am having with both is that it iterates through the entire address book to find the rooms. Is there some way I can just get the rooms list?  When going directly via Outlook, I click on new items, select meetings, select Scheduling assistant and then select "Add Rooms" and it gives me ONLY the rooms in the address list, so there must be a flag somewhere that defines an address entry as a room (as it also includes capacity as a property). This popup is immediate and I wish to achieve the same in the program I am writing.